# Attempting to implement synchronous queue backfires

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, queue

I am trying to implement my own synchronous queue using monitors. Usually< I would use the already implemented queues, but I am new to threading and I would like to see what's under the hood. My logic wraps a Linked-List inside a class, along a maximum capacity and a current capacity, plus a flag which signals there is no writer on the other end (similar to a C pipe).

**How does it work:**

- **PUSH**: While the current capacity is the maximum capacity, we wait. Else, we add the gift to the linked list and increment the capacity, followed by notify.
- **tryPOP**: While the current capacity is 0, wait. Else store the gift in a temporary variable,return it, followed by a finally block which prints(usese the toString() of the object) to print it out. If the timeout is reached, it will return null and the calling object should try again. (I did this to prevent deadlocks)

What seems to be wrong: Whenever I add something to the queue, I also print what was added and the current capacity. I see that the capacity **goes way over the maximum capacity** and I cannot seem to figure out why, since all methods are synchronized and

**Now, for some code:**

```
public class GiftQueue {
    private final Queue<Gift> factoryGiftQueue;
    private final int queueCapacity;
    private volatile int currentCapacity;
    private volatile boolean writingEndClosed;


    public GiftQueue(Queue<Gift> factoryGiftQueue, int queueCapacity) {
        this.factoryGiftQueue = factoryGiftQueue;
        this.queueCapacity = queueCapacity;
        this.currentCapacity = 0;
        this.writingEndClosed = false;

    }

    public synchronized void push(Gift gift) {
        while (currentCapacity == queueCapacity) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Queue full, awaiting pop...");
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        factoryGiftQueue.add(gift);
        currentCapacity++;
        System.out.println("Gift " + gift + " has been added to the queue. Queue size: " + currentCapacity);
        notifyAll();
    }


    public synchronized Gift tryPop(int timeoutNanos) {
        while (currentCapacity == 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Queue is empty, awaiting new push...");
                wait();
                if (currentCapacity == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Pop ABORTED");
                    return null;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
        Gift temp = factoryGiftQueue.poll();
        --currentCapacity;

        notifyAll();

        try {
            return temp;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Gift has" + temp + " been pulled from queue. Queue size " + currentCapacity);
        }


    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        System.out.println("Writing end has been closed !");
        writingEndClosed = true;
    }


    public synchronized boolean isAvailable() {
        return (!(writingEndClosed) || currentCapacity != 0);
    }

    public synchronized boolean notEmpty() {
        return currentCapacity != 0;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isFull() {
        return currentCapacity == queueCapacity;
    }

    public synchronized boolean isEmpty() {
        return currentCapacity == 0;
    }
}
```

The caller objects are:

```
public class Reindeer implements Runnable {
    private final int ID;
    private final GiftQueue factoryQueue;
    private final GiftQueue santaGiftQueue;
    private final Semaphore serviceQueue;

    public Reindeer(int ID, GiftQueue factoryQueue, GiftQueue santaGiftQueue,
                    Semaphore serviceQueue) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.factoryQueue = factoryQueue;
        this.santaGiftQueue = santaGiftQueue;
        this.serviceQueue = serviceQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (factoryQueue.isAvailable()) {
            Gift gift = null;
            System.out.println("Reindeer " + ID + " working");
            try {
                serviceQueue.acquire();
                if (factoryQueue.isEmpty()) {
                    serviceQueue.release();
                    continue;
                }
                gift = factoryQueue.tryPop(10);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                serviceQueue.release();
            }
            if (gift != null) {
                santaGiftQueue.push(gift);
                System.out.println("Reindeer " + ID + " sent a gift");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Reindeer " + ID + " will try again ");
                awaitRandom();
            }

        }

        System.out.println("Reindeer " + ID + " finished");
    }

    private void awaitRandom() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ID + "";
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Factory implements Runnable {
    private static final PositionBuilder positionBuilder = new PositionBuilder();
    private final int maxGifts;
    private final int factoryID;
    private final int matrixSize;
    private final int numberOfElves;
    private final GiftQueue giftQueue;
    private final Thread[] elvesThreads;
    private final ArrayList<ElfRunnable> elves = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final ElfBuilder elfBuilder = new ElfBuilder();
    private final FactoryElfMap elfMap;
    private final Semaphore reindeerSemaphore;
    private final WorkshopStatus workshopStatus;
    private final Semaphore serviceQueue;
    private final Orchestrator orchestrator;
    private int producedGifts;


    public Factory(int factoryID, int numberOfToysTobeProduced, int matrixSize, int numberOfElves,
                   GiftQueue giftQueue, Orchestrator orchestrator,
                   FactoryElfMap elfMap,
                   Semaphore reindeerSemaphore,
                   WorkshopStatus workshopStatus,
                   Semaphore serviceQueue) {
        this.factoryID = factoryID;
        this.maxGifts = numberOfToysTobeProduced;
        this.matrixSize = matrixSize;
        this.numberOfElves = numberOfElves;
        this.giftQueue = giftQueue;
        this.orchestrator = orchestrator;
        this.elfMap = elfMap;
        this.reindeerSemaphore = reindeerSemaphore;
        this.workshopStatus = workshopStatus;
        this.serviceQueue = serviceQueue;
        this.producedGifts = 0;
        this.elvesThreads = new Thread[numberOfElves];
        System.out.println(numberOfElves);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createElves();
        startElves();

        while (goalNotAchieved()) {
            orchestrator.awaitSupervisorTurn();
            System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " is working..");
            queryPositions();
            orchestrator.setWorkersTurn();


        }
        joinElves();

        System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " FINISHED");


        workshopStatus.signalDone();
        giftQueue.close();
    }

    public synchronized boolean goalNotAchieved() {
        return !(producedGifts == maxGifts);
    }


    private void joinElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            try {
                elvesThreads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void startElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            elvesThreads[i].start();
        }
    }

    private void createElves() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElves; i++) {
            IPosition elfPosition = positionBuilder.create(matrixSize, elfMap);
            ElfRunnable elfRunnable = elfBuilder.create(i, this, elfPosition,
                                                        orchestrator);
            elfMap.addEntry(elfRunnable, elfPosition);
            elfPosition.setOwner(elfRunnable);
            elvesThreads[i] = new Thread(elfRunnable);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void queryPositions() {
        try {
            reindeerSemaphore.acquire();
            System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " starting query....");
            for (ElfRunnable elf : elves) {
                System.out.println("   Queried " + elf + ": (" + elf.getElfPosition() + ")");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            reindeerSemaphore.release();
        }

    }


    public synchronized void becomeAware(ElfRunnable elf) {
        System.out.println("Factory " + factoryID + " got new elf");
        elves.add(elf);
    }

    public synchronized void notifyGiftCreated(Gift gift) {
        try {
            reindeerSemaphore.acquire();
            if (producedGifts == maxGifts) {
                orchestrator.setWorkersTurn();
                System.out.println("Rejecting " + gift);
            } else {
                serviceQueue.acquire();
                producedGifts++;

                if (giftQueue.isFull()) {
                    serviceQueue.release();
                    reindeerSemaphore.release();
                    notifyGiftCreated(gift);
                    return;
                }
                giftQueue.push(gift);
                System.out.println("GIFTS: " + producedGifts);
                serviceQueue.release();

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            reindeerSemaphore.release();
        }




    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return factoryID + "";
    }


}
```

Sample output:

```
Gift Gift-1329879510-34 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 1
GIFTS: 400
Reindeer 0 working
Gift hasGift-1329879510-34 been pulled from queue. Queue size 0
released
Gift Gift-1329879510-34 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 400 // <--- ???
Reindeer 1 sent a gift
Reindeer 1 working
released
Reindeer 0 working
Gift Gift-1015004123-1 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 1
GIFTS: 401
Gift hasGift-1015004123-1 been pulled from queue. Queue size 0
released
Queue full, awaiting pop...
released
Reindeer 0 working
Gift Gift--1853705096-37 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 1
GIFTS: 402
Gift hasGift--1853705096-37 been pulled from queue. Queue size 0
released
Queue full, awaiting pop...
Gift Gift-899203208-33 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 1
GIFTS: 403
Gift Gift--948848140-41 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 2
GIFTS: 404
Gift Gift--389884399-19 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 3
GIFTS: 405
Gift Gift-615746031-32 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 4
GIFTS: 406
Gift Gift-1784101203-3 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 5
GIFTS: 407
Gift Gift--1790412473-6 has been added to the queue. Queue size: 6
GIFTS: 408
```

Comment: the sources of Java standard library are open. Every library which supports parallel/asynchronous execution has own implementation of synchronized queues. Learn them first.

Comment: I am aware of that. Howevever, I am not allowed to use them.

Comment: you are not allowed to learn open source code? really?

Comment: I really like open source. I think that they are trying to teach us what is under the hood, the only downside is nobody tries to actually show us something. I will see if  there are objections to open source code.

Comment: to become a writer, one has to read many books first.